# Can I receive response from Asynchronous c# socket server with java client socket

Tags: java, c#, android-studio

Please my Asynchronous c# server socket is receiving data from the java client socket buh it not receiving response after data sent 
Java

```
@override
public void run()
try{
    inetaddress=InetAddress.getByName(" my PC IP address");
    socket=new Socket(inetaddress,port);
    DataOutputStream dat=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader buff= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
    dat.writeBytes("hello world");
    while((buff.readLine())!=null)
        Edittextcontrol.append(buff.readLine());
}
```

Comment: can you please add valid code. The while part seems to be wrong.

Comment: Am sorry for d wrong code

Comment: Thanks it has worked all I need was runOnuithread